# Two circles intersects at two points......

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

> Two circles intersect in points $A$ and $B$.$PQ$ is a line segment through $A$ and terminating on the two circles. Prove that $\frac{BP}{BQ}$ is constant for all allowable configuration of PQ.

May be it is a easy question, but I failed to answer it.I tried to rotate the small circle along the line $AB$.Please give me some hints.

Comment: Please edit the title of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be radii of our circles.

Then your statement follows immediately from the law of sines.

The hint for another way without trigonometry.

Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be centers of circles $(PAP)$ and $QAB$)$ respectively

and let $M$ and $N$ be midpoints of $PB$ and $QB$ respectively.

Prove that $\Delta PMO_1\sim\Delta QNO_2$.

Comment: Yeah, that also works as an alternate solution but the Extended Law of Sines is not usually taught in classes. (At least, not here)

Comment: @Sharky Kesa I meant $\frac{PB}{QB}=\frac{2R_1\sin\measuredangle PAB}{2R_2\sin\measuredangle QAB}=\frac{R_1}{R_2}=constant$

Comment: Yeah, I knew what you said, but the $2R$ statement is in the Extended Law of Sines. The normal Law of Sines is just $\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C}$. The Extended version is:  $\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = 2R$.

Comment: @Sharky Kesa I added another way without trigonometry.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg & Sharky Kesa I know this theorem .But please tell me I have to apply sine rule over which triangle??

Comment: @Sufaid Saleel $PB=2R_1\sin\measuredangle PAB$ for $\Delta PAB$ and $QB=2R_2\sin QAB$ for $\Delta QAB$.

Comment: @Michael Rozen..... Oops !Sorry,Got it.Thanx

Comment: @Sufaid Saleel You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This was a similar triangles problem.

Firstly, let $O_1$ be the centre of the circle on which $P$ is on and $O_2$ be the centre of the circle on which $Q$ is on.

It is easy to show $O_1 O_2$ bisects $AB$. Thus, $\angle BO_1 O_2 = \frac{1}{2} BO_1 A$.

Also, $\angle BO_1 A = 2 \angle BPA$. Thus, $\angle BO_1 O_2 = \angle BPA$.

Similarly, we can show $\angle BO_2 O_1 = \angle BQA$.

Thus, $\Delta BO_1 O_2 \sim BPQ$ since they are equiangular. Therefore, $\frac{BP}{BQ}=\frac{BO_1}{BO_2}$, which always remains constant.

Thus, proven.